# Lagrange's Multiplier Method

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I need to find the distance between the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{y^2}{9} = 1$ and the line $y = 10 - 2x$ using Lagranges' Multiplier Method.
So far I know how to find the minimum distance between origin and any curve using this method but unable to apply the concept in this case.

Comment: You could consider the function of 4 variables defined by $F(x,y,z,t)=(x-z)^2+(y-t)^2$ and use Lagrange multipliers to minimize it under the two "constraints" you are given, i.e. $(x,y)$ is on the ellipse and $(z,t)$ is on the line.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong

Comment: @AlexanderVigodner Sorry for what?

Comment: I added wrong comment, removed it and apologized :). I don't know how to remove the comment completely

Comment: OK, I understand. Don't worry about that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hint:

line    $ y=10-2x$ can be written as $2x+y-10=0$

for any point$(x,y)$, the distance $d$ of the point to the line $ax+by+c=0 $ is

$d=\dfrac{|ax+by+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=f(x,y)$

and the point is on the ellipse $\implies g=\dfrac{x^2}{4} + \dfrac{y^2}{9} - 1$

$F=f+ \lambda   g$